# How to add a password to the storage in Firefox with a script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, passwords, thunderbird

I have a task to add a password, username and password to the Saved Passwords in Firefox, so that the new account can log in and work on the local site, without additional password entries.

What kind of script is needed, import is inappropriate here, I can copy local.json and key.bd with the same success

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating a form tag:

```html
<form>

</form>
```

You can then create password and email fields:

```html
<form>
<input type="email">
<input type="password">
</form>
```

And if you add a button with the type "submit":

```html
<form>
<input type="email">
<input type="password">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

When the user submits the form (by clicking the type="submit" button) they will be asked if they want to save their email and password in the browser. If they say yes, it will be saved.